# Acceptable parameters for -Confirm when creating azure resource

Tags: azure, locking, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create a resource lock on azure via the powershell, as per the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcelock?view=azps-5.2.0

I am attemtping to create a resourceLock with the following code:

```
 New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName locktest -Scope <MySubscription>
```

This will work perfectly, However after entering it will ask for confirmation, with the following confirmation message:

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Creating the lock." on target
"subscriptions/*************/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/locktest".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

I am looking for a way to run this cmdlet without the confirmation message. As per the posted documentation, the cmd should accept a -Confirm option, however I cannot seem to find an acceptable input. I have tried running the cmdlet as follows:

```
 New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName locktest -Scope <MySubscription> -Confirm False
```

Allthough this just results in the following error message.

```
New-AzResourceLock : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'False'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName locktest -Scope  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzResourceLock], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementat
   ion.NewAzureResourceLockCmdlet
```

What parameters will i need to use in order to skip the confirmation option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Force` parameter.

```
New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName locktest -Scope <MySubscription> -Force
```

This will facilitates running the commandlet without prompting for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the parameter `-Confirm` in your Powershell command, you should specify it as `-Confirm:$false`.

Besides, if you want to run the command `New-AzResourceLock` to create resource lock without any confirmation,  you should also add the parameter `-force`. Because the `confirm` is used to control whether to confirm before running the cmdlet. But when running the command, we also need to confirm. So we need to use `-force`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/63193bf2bdb03ae30a175570fce0095864ddb093/src/Resources/ResourceManager/Implementation/Lock/NewAzureResourceLockCmdlet.cs#L59)